# How to select which instance to update with command line in Installshield (silent mode)?

Tags: command-line, installshield, updates, silent

I have an installscript project (non MSI), which is in multi-instance mode.
In most cases, the setup.exe will be launched from command line in silent mode.

Then, new versions of the program will be generated, and we may have to update som instances that are already installed on the machine.
The problem is that i don't know how to select which instance I want to update from cmdline (in silent mode).
Is there a way to do this ?

I've noticed that there is a /ig switch, that enables me to use a specific instance GUID, but it does not seem to let me select an instance by its guid...

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

To update a specific instance you need :

- a record file correspondig to update mode (to get it, you have to run the setup.exe with cmdline in record mode : `setup.exe /r /f1"/full/path/to/your/recordfile.iss"`
- The GUID of the instance you want to update : this guid is contained in the installscript "INSTANCE_GUID" variable. You can write it into a file during the installation of your instance.

Then, you can update the instance with the following command line :

```
setup.exe /r /f1"/full/path/to/your/recordfile.iss" /ig"{your-guid-goes-here}"
```

this did the trick for me.